# Context Path not considered in HATEOAS links when upgrading from Spring Boot 1.5.9 to 2.2.6

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-hateoas, hateoas

I have recently upgraded an older application, based on Spring Boot, from version 1.5.9 to 2.2.6.

Unfortunately, after upgrading, the urls generated with HATEOAS are changed. Basically the context-path is missing from the Links now.

Example:

```
Before: https://domain.test.com/service/api/endpoint
Now:    https://domain.test.com/service/endpoint
```

Right now I am using the following configs in application properties:

```
server.servlet.context-path: /api
server.forward-headers-strategy: FRAMEWORK
spring.data.rest.basePath: /api
```

(With none, the host is totally different(because of the x-forwarded-host. I have also tried with native, but same behavior)

I have also created a **ForwardedHeaderFilter** bean.

```
    @Bean
    public ForwardedHeaderFilter forwardedHeaderFilter() {
        return new ForwardedHeaderFilter();
    }
```

Is there anything I can do to bypass this issue? Am I doing something wrong ?

One alternative would be to adjust the api gateway, but this would be really complicated from a business process perspective so I would prefer a more technical approach.

Thank you !

Comment: i am dealing with this now, what did you end up doing?

Comment: @futevolei I updated the answer with my current solution

Comment: cool.  We fixed our issue by adding this: @Bean
    ForwardedHeaderFilter forwardedHeaderFilter() {
        return new ForwardedHeaderFilter();
    }

Comment: @futevolei I am using this in combination with the utility class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a temporary solution, until I have time to really take a deeper look, I have created a new Utility class, that takes care of adjusting the path:

```java
public class LinkUtil {
    private LinkUtil() {
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    public static <T> Link linkTo(T methodOn) {
        String rawPath = WebMvcLinkBuilder.linkTo(methodOn).toUri().getRawPath();
        rawPath = StringUtils.remove(rawPath, "/service");
        BasicLinkBuilder basicUri = BasicLinkBuilder.linkToCurrentMapping().slash("/api").slash(rawPath);

        return new Link(basicUri.toString());
    }
}
```

Where `/api` is the context-path.

Then I use it like this:

```java
Link whateverLink = LinkUtil.linkTo(methodOn(WhateverClass.class).whateverMethod(null)).withRel("whatever-rel));
```

Answer (score 0):

@LoolKovski's temporary solution relies on an existing ServletRequest because of #linkToCurrentMapping. Use the following code if you, too, need to eliminate that restriction:

```
public class LinkUtil {
    private LinkUtil() {
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    public static <T> Link linkTo(T methodOn) {
        var originalLink = WebMvcLinkBuilder.linkTo(methodOn);
        var rawPathWO = StringUtils.remove(originalLink.toUri().getRawPath(), "/service");
        return originalLink.withHref("/api" + rawPathWO);
    }
}
```

Actually, in my case the links are generated during one of the RestController beans' initialization, so my real code looks like the following code.
I don't need to cut-off some other path part before but only need to prepend a configured context path.

```
@RestController
public class ExampleController implements ServletContextAware {

@Override
public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
    final var executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executor.submit(() -> {
        someRepository.getExamples().forEach((name, thing) -> {
            Link withRel = linkTo(methodOn(ExampleController.class).getElement(null, name, null))
                    .withSelfRel();
            withRel = withRel.withHref(servletContext.getContextPath() + withRel.toUri().getRawPath());
            thing.add(withRel);
        });
        executor.shutdown();
    });
}

@RequestMapping(path = "/{name}/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public HttpEntity<Example> getElement(ServletWebRequest req, @PathVariable("name") String name, Principal principal) {
    [...]
}
```